# деструктуризация

Tags: javascript

в цикле если раскоментить деструктуризацию и удалить ниже item и оставить просто name и quantity, name вроде работает quantity увеличиваться не хочет, я где то ошибся или просто не понимаю как работает деструктуризация ?

```js
const cart = {
  items: [],
  add(product) {
    let {items} = this
    
    for (let item of items) {
      // let {name, quantity} = item
      if (item.name === product.name) {
        item.quantity += 1
        return
      }
    }
    const newProd = {...product, quantity: 1}
    
    items.push(newProd)
  },
}

cart.add({name: 'apple', price: 50})
cart.add({name: 'lemon', price: 60})
cart.add({name: 'lemon', price: 60})

console.log(cart.items)
```

Comment: Деструктуризация это просто сокращенная запись присваивания. Каогда вы пишите `a = item.quantity; a += 1` вы же не ожидаете что `item.quantity` изменится?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Локальная переменная `quantity` и поле объекта `product.quantity` никак не связаны между собой. Если нужно изменить поле объекта надо работать с полем объекта, не его копией.

Хотя оператор `a += 1;` выглядит как модификация значения объекта `a` это не так. Этот оператор точная копия выражения `a = a + 1;`. Выражение `a + 1` создаёт новый объект и этот новый объект присваивается старой переменной. Другие переменные, которые ссылались на исходное значение `a`, продолжат на него ссылаться:

```
// a
//  \
//   ---> 1
//  /
// b

a += 1;

//  a ---> 2
//  b ---> 1
```

Дополнительную путаницу вносит то что есть языки (С++) в которых `+=` может модифицировать объект, а не создавать новую копию. В таких языках `a += 1` может, если программист постарается, поменять значение `b`.

Почитайте про [value object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object). Числа и строки в JavaScript объекты-значения, что здорово облегчает жизнь программисту.

```js
let product = {'quantity': 1};

let {quantity} = product;

console.log('product.quantity', product.quantity);
console.log('quantity', quantity);

quantity += 2;

console.log('product.quantity', product.quantity);
console.log('quantity', quantity);

product.quantity += 3;

console.log('product.quantity', product.quantity);
console.log('quantity', quantity);
```

Comment: почему то думал в quantity будет ссылка на свойство обьекта а не копия. вроде понял, спасибо